# Регулярное выражение - перечисление

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Из строки такого формата: `41=26; 42=27,5; 43=28;`, необходимо получить значения 41, 42 и 43.

Пытался сделать с помощью вариантов, но если число с запятой, например 27,5, то дальше запятой выражение не работает.

```
(...)[0-9][0-9][,.|;]\s(...)[0-9][0-9][,.|;]\s(...)[0-9][0-9][,.|;]
```

Подскажите, как можно решить задачу?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4rSflx/1

Comment: `(?<=^|;\s)\d+(?=\=)`

Answer (score 0):

Для `php`:

```php
$str = '41=26; 42=27,5; 43=28;';
preg_match_all('/\d+(?=\=)/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Выражение: [(\d+?)=](https://regex101.com/r/tqLfRc/1)

Пример на python:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+?)=', '41=26; 42=27,5; 43=28;')
['41', '42', '43']
```

---

Выражение: [\d+?=(.+?);](https://regex101.com/r/86JldR/1)

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+?=(.+?);', '41=26; 42=27,5; 43=28;')
['26', '27,5', '28']
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Java

```java
String pattern = "41=26; 42=27,5; 43=28;";

pattern = pattern.replaceAll("(^|[^\\d]+)(\\d+)(\\=.*?\\;)", "$2, ");

System.out.println(pattern); // 41, 42, 43,
```

**Расшифровка:**

- `(^|[^\\d]+)` - группировка `$1` - начало строки, либо некая последовательность (1 и более) нецифровых символов
- `(\\d+)` - группировка `$2` - некая последовательность (1 и более) цифровых символов
- `(\\=.*?\\;)` - группировка `$3` - последовательность начинается со знака `'='`, далее идет последовательность любых символов (0 и более), минимально возможная до символа `';'`